# Why i can't compare ValueError message with string in urllib module?

Tags: error-handling, python-3.3

In python3:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
try:
    req = Request("wrong url")
except ValueError as e:
    if e == "unknown url type: 'wrong url'" :print("bad url")
```

Why there is no `bad url` to output in my python console?
Can't compare ValueError message with string

1.Think for you to tell me 'str(e)'
2.It is "unknown url type: 'wrong url'" not "unknown url type: wrong url"  ,I have test it in my console.

Comment: fine I was using version 3.2.3 and it does not have the quotes. Just goes to show the issues with relying on string comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing an exception object to a string

You should compare to `str(e)` to get a match e.g.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
try:
    req = Request("wrong url")
except ValueError as e:
    if "unknown url type" in str(e) :
        print("bad url")
```

The line

```
if "unknown url type" in str(e) :
```

Accounts for differences in the returned string between python 3.x version.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass it to `str` first:

```
if str(e) == "unknown url type: 'wrong url'" :
```